# X and Y are independent uniform random variables distributed in [-1,1], how do I find $P[ X^2 < \frac{1}{2}, |Y| < \frac{1}{2}]$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

- Since $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed in $[-1,1]$:

$f_Y(y) = f_X(x) = \frac{1}{1-(-1)} = \frac{1}{2}$ over $-1 \leq y \leq 1$ and $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ respectively, and $0$ everywhere else for each of the RVs.

- Then the only place $Y < \frac{1}{2} = 1 - \int_{-1}^{1} f_Y(y) = 0$
- It seems intuitive to me that given the above, regardless of the first constraint $|X| < \frac{1}{2}$ should then be 0. Since $0 \cap S = 0$

However the answer in my solution manual indicates that:

$P[|X|<\frac{1}{2}]P[Y<\frac{1}{2}] = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, and I'm not sure how it arrives there...

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: Can you explain your intuition behind the sentence "regardless of the first constraint $|X|<\frac12$ should then be $0$?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we have $$\Pr[(X^2 \le 1/2) \cap (|Y| \le 1/2)] = \Pr[X^2 \le 1/2]\Pr[Y \le 1/2].$$  Since they are uniform on $[-1,1]$, we then have $$\Pr[X^2 \le 1/2] = \Pr[-1/\sqrt{2} \le X \le 1/\sqrt{2}] = \frac{1/\sqrt{2} - (-1/\sqrt{2})}{1 - (-1)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},$$ and $$\Pr[|Y| \le 1/2] = \Pr[-1/2 \le Y \le 1/2] = \frac{(1/2)-(-1/2)}{1-(-1)} = \frac{1}{2},$$ and the claimed result follows.  In both cases, we used the fact that if a random variable $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[a,b]$ with $a < b$, we have $$\Pr[c < U < d] = \frac{d-c}{b-a}, \quad a < c < d < b.$$

Comment: Hey I was thinking about your solution - does your answer for P[Y<1/2]  change if its strictly less than half and not less than equals to half?

Comment: No it doesn't. Notice that $P(Y = \frac{1}{2}) = 0$ therefore $P(Y \leq \frac{1}{2}) =P(Y < \frac{1}{2}) $

Comment: Alright - I understand. I misunderstood that term to mean P[Y]<1/2, and I got pigeon holed into reading it like that, repeatedly . Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

1. $X^2< \frac12\iff |X|<\frac1{\sqrt2}$.
2. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $|X|$ and $|Y|$ are also independent.
3. Complete the sentence: if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $P(A, B) = ...$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that because of independence: 
\begin{equation}
P\left(X^2 < \frac{1}{2}, |Y| < \frac{1}{2} \right) = P\left(X^2 < \frac{1}{2}\right) P\left(|Y| < \frac{1}{2} \right)
\end{equation}

Analyzing the $X$ term: 
\begin{equation}
P\left(X^2 < \frac{1}{2}\right) = P \left( -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < X < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{equation}

While the $Y$ term: 
\begin{equation}
P\left(|Y| < \frac{1}{2} \right) = P\left(\frac{1}{2} <Y < \frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}

Substituting both results in the first equation: 
\begin{equation}
P\left(X^2 < \frac{1}{2}, |Y| < \frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{equation}